# How to recreate Eclipse's ignoring of binary incompatibilities in an Ant javac invocation?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javac

Eclipse provides a Java build-time option to ignore problems with incompatible required binaries at compile-time (see screenshot below; Ignore is the default actually):

[image: Eclipse Java building options]

I had needed this because I'm compiling a library on Eclipse Indigo (which I believe internally uses a 1.7 compiler) with a 1.6 target, but which is dependent on a library with a 1.8 target. (Everything will still be run on a 1.8 JVM where that dependent library is used, so I want the compilation to work.)

However, when I came to translate this to an Ant `javac` task in a build script, I've no idea how to specify this option (or, indeed, whether it boils down to a single compiler option). Having a look at the [Java 6 javac 'man page'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) doesn't suggest anything obvious. (I appreciate that I am here using a 1.6 compiler — I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 which still has Java 1.6 —  instead of Eclipse's internal 1.7 one, but that shouldn't affect the question.)

So:

(i) What does this boil down to in terms of javac options (or, equivalently, how is Eclipse achieving this?)?

(ii) How, if at all, is this translateable to an Ant `javac` task invocation?

Comment: The Eclipse help also just says what the option does, not how it achieves it. As a Billy Bonus aside, is there no way to set Eclipse to show the exact commands it is using under-the-covers somewhere (which would be a nice general way to work out some of these things)?

Comment: Eclipse has its own Java compiler

Comment: @greg-449 Yes (I think Indigo has a 1.7 one) but that doesn't invalidate the question does it? (Eclipse is still presumably using some compiler options to achieve the effect. I *guess* the 1.7 compiler could have a new option to this effect that 1.6 doesn't have, but I can't see anything in the javac 1.7 man page either...)

Comment: @greg-449 Edited the question to make this clear; I agree that I phrased it in a way which suggests I didn't realise this.

Comment: The Eclipse Java compiler is not a copy of the javac compiler, it is a different compiler altogether with different options. You can use the Eclipse compiler in Ant as described [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-ant_javac_adapter.htm) and [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm)

Comment: @greg-449 Ah that Changes Everything! That second link of yours lists all the ECJ compile options but I *still* can't see anything relating to these binary incompatibilities. I'll have more of a poke around...

Comment: Well, by using ECJ for compilation with default options it works (so many thanks greg-449), though it still remains a mystery how these explicit options translate to ECJ options. (If I wanted to set it to error, how would I do that?). @greg-449: if you want to add an answer to this effect I will accept it (and will add to it with an edit if I ever find out how these options actually map to ECJ options, given that you don't know or find out first).

Comment: Ah I'm still stuck because the same binary incompatibility error gets reported by javadoc, and that *does* use the 'native' JDK's javadoc (i.e., it seems there is no Eclipse-provided 'ECJ-matching' alternative). Perhaps I resign myself to requiring a Java 1.8 build environment...

Answer (score 0):

To see the command that Eclipse is running when you click "Run":

- Go to the Debug window, which is generally within the Debug perspective
- Expand your application and right click on Java executable underneath (image below in case that's badly explained)

[image: Expanded application]

- Click Properties and see the Command Line box

It could be that Eclipse is explicitly excluding the incompatible library? Hopefully it shows up in the command line box here.

Comment: But this is a *compile-time* thing, not a runtime one. It is definitely using the library (just ignoring the binary incompatibility) because it's required for the compilation. This trick is still handy for other things though so thanks!